The view function for 'form' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement
Not sure why I am getting this error. any help?
from flask import Flask, request # type: ignore

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ["Get", "Post"])
def form():
    if request.method == "Post":
        name = request.form["name"]
        email = request.form["email"]
        return '''
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Simple Form</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Simple Form</h1>
            <form method = "POST" action = "/">
                <lebale for = "name"> Name: </label>
                <input type = "text" id = "name" name = "name">
                <label for = "email" > Email: </label> 
                <input type = "email" id = "email" name = "email">
                <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
            </form>
        </body>
        </html> '''
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug = True)

Need help with error 'The view function for 'form' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.'

request.method probably doesn't match "Post" (title cased), and even if it did, there's no code to handle the case when the request method isn't POST.
